# How to fetch and update data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-blade, laravel-8

So, I have two fields. In the first field I want to add old data and in the second field I want to add new data, and below those fields is a button which when clicked will fetch the data from Mongo Table and update the data inside.
I have tried implementing various logic but still no luck. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

This is my controller code:

```
public function updatedockets($dockets){
    if (!Session::has('user_id')){
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
    $cart = \App\Models\Cart::where('tracking_no',$dockets)->get()->toArray();
    foreach ($cart as $value) {
        $cart = \App\Models\Cart::where('tracking_no')->update(['tracking_no' => $dockets]);
     }   
 }
```

This is my view code:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="docket-replace">
                    <form method="post" id="frmDocket" action="/admin/viewdockets">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="txtreploaceDockets" name="replacedockets" class="form-control" rows="15" placeholder="Enter old docket(s) here. Don't put more than 1000 docket numbers, all dockets should be comma(,) or new line separated"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form> 

                    <form method="post" id="frmDocket" action="/admin/viewdockets">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="txtreplaceDockets" name="replacedockets" class="form-control" rows="15" placeholder="Enter new docket(s) here. Don't put more than 1000 docket numbers, all dockets should be comma(,) or new line separated"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="text-right pr-sm-15 pb-sm-15">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btnReplaceDocketData"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure that you have entered the right docket number?')"> Replace Docket </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
```

Comment: try this $cart = \App\Models\Cart::where('tracking_no',$dockets)->update(['tracking_no' => $dockets]);

Comment: there is something bizarre in your controller code, adding to @JohnLobo, you fetch carts where 'tracking_no' = $dockets and then you update the cart with  'tracking_no' = $dockets, plus you're only saving the last cart you fetched it!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, fetch the data from the table and then update the data in the same id. For e.g if a=1 and I want to change it to 5 then a=5, That's what I'm trying to implement, I know the code seems messy, it's giving me a headache now.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using `$value`, maybe below code helps you:

```
$cart = \App\Models\Cart::where('tracking_no', $dockets)
    ->update(['tracking_no' => $dockets]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
$course->statuses()->updateOrCreate(
    ['status_id' => $id],
    ['status' => $request->get('status'), 'status_type' => Course::class]
);`
```